# What books explain Spanish's difficulties?

Tags: recursos, lingüística, latín

I use `explicate` (the cognate of  *explicar*) to mean 'conjecture or explain possible reasons or origins', rather than books like [Breaking Out of Beginner's Spanish](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0292761937) and [1001 Pitfalls in Spanish](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764143476) which only state the difficulties with no explication whatsoever.

What books explicate Spanish's difficulties, especially those counterintuitive to an Anglophone or Francophone?  I exemplify my meaning of 'difficulties' below, which no grammar book have explicated; I found the explications on Wikipedia's page about 'Vulgar Latin'.

---

> [[1.]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages#Development_from_Latin) [...]  Generally, the personal pronoun is unreduced (beyond normal sound change), while the article has suffered various amounts of reduction, e.g. Spanish *ella* "she" < *illa* vs. *la* "the (fem.)" < *-la* < *illa*.

The  book must explicate such connections between  words (or Functional Morphemes).

> [[2.]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_copula#Spanish) Most languages have one main copula, but some, such as Spanish and some other Romance languages, have more than one. This is because the verb or verbs meaning "to be" in the [Romance languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_language) are derived from not just one but THREE Latin verbs [...]

1 introduced me to 2. Unhelpfully, grammar books neglect Latin copulas (sedēre, esse, stāre), which otherwise would easily aid learners to disambiguate *ser* vs *estar*, partly because:

2.1. they both are more specific than 'to be' and 'être'; though a cognate of *estar*, 'être' is broader because it subsumes the meanings of *ser*.

2.2. knowledge of the Romance Copula explicates the irregularity of the conjugation of  *être*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for using Spanish SE and keep up learning Spanish, unfortunately this is not the right place where to ask for resources, a lot of books out there implies many answers, which is the correct one?

Comment: Welcome to our site. Our community determined early on that we were not well suited to answering questions about learning resources in our format. Usually resources such as Amazon.com (which I know you use) are much better able to provide recommendations for these sorts of things. I hope, though, that you'll stick around, and find other aspects of our site helpful.